Correctly decode accented chars in XPKeywords from image EXIF data in Windows app using C# or VB.NET
I am facing an encoding issue I can't seem to solve since I'm no real encoding expert...
I am entering XPKeywords information in some of my numerous images in Windows so that I could sort them out later on using these keywords.
I did a test on one of the images, adding some French accented chars such as é, è, à etc...
Adding a keyword containing 'é' for instance displays ok in my French Windows Explorer.
However accessing the tag using C#/VB displays "�". I tried all sorts of conversions, googled for XPKeywords and found that XPKeywords seems encoded in UCS-2 but can't still find any way to correctly decode this field so that I can display correct info.
Probably easy but cannot figure it out.
Any hint would be greatly appreciated.
Thx

Can you please post the relevant part of your code?

Show the minimal code snippet from your current app to read an image, even though it's still incorrect. That will give us context we need to suggest corrections.

Also, specify how you edited the metadata of your images, it may affect the way the data is stored. Post the numeric identifier of the PropertyItem you're referring to as XPKeywords (could be the field that contains strings separated by a semicolon, but you have to be specific). The PropertyItem Type (e.g., PropertyTagTypeASCII vs. PropertyTagTypeUndefined) can be useful. Note that PropertyTagTypeASCII, despite the name, can be anything, since just the bytes are stored and considered (you can store UTF-8 / UTF-16 encoded strings)

You need to make sure that whatever you're using to view the text can display it correctly.

Got this to work.
Encoding value used within the GetString function was defined as UTF-8. Changing it to Unicode did the trick.
Thanks to all for the heads up!
